# React contextAPI fetch not updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-reducer

I'm using `contextAPI` and trying to fetch data and update state using action and reducer, but the state is not getting updated

im using `fetch` inside `useEffect` and after fetch i dispatch type `GET_EMPLOYEES`

**AuthContext.js**

```
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";

const initialState = {

  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  employees: [],
  isLoading: false,
  darken: false,
};

const AuthContext = React.createContext(initialState);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getEmployees = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-employees");
      const data = await response.json();
      dispatch({ type: "GET_EMPLOYEES", payload: data });
    };
    getEmployees();
  }, []);
}
```

i made reducer to update state, in case of `GET_EMPLOYEES`, it should return state as is but update `employees` with action `payload`.

**AuthReducer.js**

```
const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
       case "LOGIN":
      return {
        user: null,
        isLoading: true,
      };

    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case "GET_EMPLOYEES":
      return { ...state, employees: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

i made action type `GET_EMPLOYEES`, and in case of dispatched, it sends back payload

**AuthAction.js**

```
export const login = () => ({
  type: "LOGIN",
});

export const loginSuccess = (user) => ({
  type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
  payload: user,
});

export const getEmployees = (employees) => ({
  type:"GET_EMPLOYEES",
  payload: employees
});
```

finally trying to access `employees` state from `AuthContext` using `useContext`

**RequestVacation.jsx**

```
import AuthContext from "../../../context/AuthContext";

function RequestVacationForm() {

  const { employees } = useContext(AuthContext);

  console.log(isLoading); // false
  console.log(employees); // undefined

}
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provider must return something

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getEmployees = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/get-employees");
      const data = await response.json();
      dispatch({ type: "GET_EMPLOYEES", payload: data });
    };
    getEmployees();
  }, []);
}

return <AuthContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Other than that it works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-bash-qenf4h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: oh, it turned out that i forgot to include ```employees``` in ```value``` prop

Comment: But why when I go from login page to employees page it doesn't get employees state, but if I navigate from any other page it works fine!